# Is ok to add [BsonAttribute] to POCOs?

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, poco

I have an application, structured like this:

```
Application.Domain
Application.Web.Mvc
Application.MongoDb
```

In `Application.Domain` i keep all the POCOs of the application (the domain models).

```
public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, because i am using `MongoDb`, i also need to use some of the `[BsonAttribute]`, in order to customize the serialization process.

For example:

```
public class Product
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local, DateOnly = true)] 
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

If i add these attributes, i will need to also add a reference to `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes` in the `Application.Domain` project, which i want to avoid.

I think the correct way to do this is to create mapping objects in the `Application.MongoDb` project, and always map them from POCO to MongoObjects and the other way around every time i work with MongoDb repos.

If this is the correct solution, isn't this a bit overkill?

Comment: You can use attribute in Domain Model as long as you do not expose them as View Model to client-side.

Comment: Ok, but adding the attributes to Domain Models makes the `Domain` project depend on `MongoDb` library, which breaks the principle if you want to change to something else in the future